# Fail to install Starman inside Docker container

Tags: perl, docker

I'm trying to create a Docker container for an app with starman perl server

So  my Dockerfile looks like this  :

```
FROM        perl:latest
MAINTAINER  perl5 drd.trif@gmail.com
RUN curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus


RUN cpanm  Carton Starman


RUN cachebuster=b953b35 git clone -b pb_on_docker --single-branch https://github.com/DragosTrif/PearlBee.git

RUN cd PearlBee && carton install  && carton install --deployment 
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR PearlBee

CMD carton exec starman --port 8080 bin/app.psgi
```

But it fails to install Starman

I checked the `build.log`  and found this error :

```
2016/09/27-08:18:16 Starman::Server (type Net::Server::PreFork) starting! pid(13467)
Missing port in hashref passed in port argument.
2016/09/27-08:41:17 Starman::Server (type Net::Server::PreFork) starting! pid(13468)
Missing port in hashref passed in port argument.
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: I'v edited my post and added  my Dockerfile.

Comment: So `Starman` has some general issues with `Net::Server` https://github.com/miyagawa/Starman/issues/119

Comment: Are `PearlBee` and `PearBee` supposed to be the same thing in your `RUN` and `WORKDIR` lines?

Comment: Yes I edited to fix the typo.